# XAML, C# : How to Set ListView Visibility to Collapse/Visible on Checkbox value toggle?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

i am newbie in C# and Windows app development, just for learning purpose i am trying to build a Windows 10 universal app. I am experimenting with Hub view.

Below is the Xaml structure of my file.

```
   <Hub>
       <HubSection1>
       //SomeData here
       </HubSection1>

       <HubSection2>
          <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
              <ListView1>
                         <CheckBox1>
                                   <ListView2>
                                        //SomeData here

                         <CheckBox2>
                                   <ListView3>
                                         //SomeData here

                         <CheckBox3>
                                   <ListView4>
                                         //SomeData here

              </ListView1>

           </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>

       </HubSection2>

       <HubSection3>
       //SomeData here
       </HubSection3>

       <HubSection4>
       //SomeData here
       </HubSection4>

    </Hub>
```

So what i am trying to do is to toggle the visibility of ListView(2,3,4) Using Checkboxes(1,2,3) respectively. But in my c# sharp code i am unable to access the variables defined in my XAML file, i tried FindName() in checkbox listeners Method but it didn't helped. is there any way i can fetch data or variables or bind them ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use converter concept:

```
public class BooleanToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isChecked = false;
        if (bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out isChecked))
        {
            return isChecked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return visibility;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Windows.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <converters:BooleanToVisibility x:Key="boolToVisibility"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <CheckBox Content="Check to see ListView" Name="changeVisibility"/>
        <ListView Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=changeVisibility, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Or you can use the built-in `BoolToVisibilityConverter` instead of creating your own.

Comment: @MikeEason How to implement that ??

Comment: @Andrei M , your code is showing error on `out visibility` that `Argument 2: cannot convert out Windows.Ui.Xaml.visibility to out bool` and `isChecked doesn't exist n current context`.

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 I see. Hard to work without VS :). Fixed